# Could not find the Android Studio installation at the manually configured path

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Folks, I'm new in VsCode and Flutter development. I followed all the steps according to Flutter's official setup guide. But now I'm getting this error saying that my PATH is incorrect.
Please help me. I just want to make simple application for android. FYI, I have already installed the Android Studio. There's something like Command-Line tools that I think is not installed.
Can anyone tell me how do I install that tool?

I tried finding it on youtube and all over internet but couldn't find any proper answer.

Comment: Can you specify your PATH?

Comment: You cant also start flutter app development in android studio. No need to vs code.

In ubuntu check environment path.
$echo $PATH
Check flutter sdk path
Which operating system used?
post error screen short or error code.